# How to wrap calls with try/catch block?

Tags: c++

Suppose, I have different functions, which can throw exceptions:

```
const Foo& func_foo(...);  // Can throw exceptions
const Bar& func_bar(...);  // Can throw exceptions
const FooBar& func_foobar(...); // Can throw exceptions
```

I have different places in code, which can use such functions in following way:

```
some_func(/*applying of func_foo or func_bar or func_foobar*/(...))
```

Actually, I am using result of functions immediately in many places within different functions.

What is best way to wrap calling of func_foo/func_bar_func_foobar functions with try/catch block without global rewriting of other pieces of code?

Ideally I want to use something like that (for example to call func_foo)

```
some_func(TRY_CATCH_BLOCK(func_foo(...)));
```

catch handler will propagate exception with different types

```
catch (const ExceptionFoo& e)
{
   throw SomeException1("Some message from e");
}
catch (const ExceptionBar& e)
{
   throw SomeException2("Some message from e");
}
```

Comment: Who should be handling the catch?  Is it the callee or caller's?

Comment: What should be done in the `catch` ? Something akin to logging and rethrowing ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I must admit that I find combining lambdas and macros quite fun.

```
#define TRY_CATCH_BLOCK(...)         \
    [&]() -> decltype(auto) {        \
        try {                        \
            return __VA_ARGS__;      \
        } catch(/* ... */) {         \
            /* Handle and rethrow */ \
        }                            \
    }()
```

This can be called just like you specified, including interleaved inside another function call.

```
some_func(TRY_CATCH_BLOCK(func_foo(...)));
```

[See it live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/8d02af823af59602)

Comment: Is it possible to do something similar using a template function?

Comment: @IUnknown not with the same terseness, no. Dropping return type forwarding you could achieve `some_func(try_catch_block([&]{ return func_foo(...); }));`, but I don't see a way to simplify that.